# How to query GIS data for overlaps?

Tags: query, overlapping-features

I am trying to get a list of Election Districts inside particular City Council Districts in Brooklyn, NY. The data that is available is GIS data, visible here:

- City Council Districts: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/City-Council-Districts/yusd-j4xi
- Election Districts: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Election-Districts/h2n3-98hq

What I need is to somehow link these datasets and generate a list (not a visualization in this case) of Election District (ED) numbers by City Council District (CCD) numbers. I'm totally new to GIS so can someone give me some direction about how this might be done?

The tough part it seems to me is to link the data by area so as to match the two sets of numbers.

Is this possible somehow?

Is there query language associated with GIS through which one could do this?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? The procedure you want is probably 'Spatial Join' which can be done in many different GIS softwares.

Comment: I finally figured this out by reading docs from carto.com, which is what I ended up using. I'm on a Mac so I think I can only use online tools as ArcGIS is for windows? Will add my solution in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Using QGIS I would suggest the following:

- With the realcentroid-Plugin calculate the centroid within the polygon of the Election Districts
- With the spatialJoin-Plugin join the centroid-Layer with the City Council Districts

[image]

If you want to import the data into postGIS it would be even easier. There is a function st_pointonsurface which would be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

While @aleho's answer looks good, I ended up just using SQL with a "spatial join", which was the concept I was missing I think. The query I used looks like this:

```
SELECT nycc.coundist, nyed.electdist, nyed.the_geom
FROM nyed, nycc
WHERE ST_Intersects(nycc.the_geom, nyed.the_geom)
GROUP BY nycc.coundist, nyed.electdist, nyed.the_geom
ORDER BY nycc.coundist
```

I executed this inside a tool called carto.com that allowed me to import the two data sets and query them against each other.

Comment: Great - I didnt know the technology you are using... I think it would be better to query with st_pointonsurface and then st_within - st_intersect can be wrong, if the boundaries aren't precise and overlap. You could use: ST_Within(st_pointonsurface(nyed.the_geom), nycc.the_geom)